# Maven version range pattern to find one before latest

Tags: maven-2, maven

I need to create maven version pattern to get one before latest artifact. I know that i can use [0,) to get latest one, but is there a possibility to search for one before?

Comment: Interesting question. I tried the to find an answer in ["Maven, the complete reference"](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html) to no avail. But I'd like to find out what the difference is between `[x,)` and `[x,]`. If I'd had to guess it would be the difference to the latest version exclusive and inclusive.

Comment: @pjanssen `[x,)` and `[x,]` can be seen as `[x,∞)` and `[x,∞]` which is both `>= x`. See [Dependency Mediation and Conflict Resolution.](https://web.archive.org/web/20131214104924/http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution)

Comment: Also available here: https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html

Answer (score 0):

I ended up downloading POM of latest version, getting latest_version from it and using pattern [0, latest_version).